# If I use dump() in Symfony3 the debug toolbar is hide

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I'm just learning Symfony3, and if I use this code:

```
dump($em->getRepository('AppBundle:Genus'));
```

without `die;`, the Debug tool bar is hidden. I watched the HTML code page - it all works, debug panel exists, but add the class `sf-display-none`, so the panel is not visible.

Why? How to fix it?

While it is necessary to remove this class in the manual.

Comment: Dumping out a full repository is a bit unusual.  A repository is a big class with all kinds of references to other classes.  I would not expect it to mess up the tool bar but if it does then just don't do that.

Comment: It might be more helpful for you to tell us what you want to dump? Maybe you want to see what is stored in the Genus Entity?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your attention. The problem is not class size - even output a simple variable did the panel is hidden. All appeared easier - Adguard did something, which hadn't been remove or added the class of hide panel. Just added the domain to the exceptions adguard and everything works now!